# AngularJS analogue to jQuery preventDefault for keydown?

Tags: angularjs

I need the browser to respond to keydown arrow events in focused scrollable boxes.
Here is a Plunker to show what I mean

http://plnkr.co/edit/Okch5dEByFkueJl0DmwG

Even if I tell the event to stop propagating with `event.stopPropagation()`
and make the event handler return `false`  the box keeps scrolling on keydown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken as far as what you're looking for, you should just be able to change your

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

back to

```
event.preventDefault()
```

and it will work as desired.